# Opening another (mine) application from my main application Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, uiapplication

I have two applications and i want to open them from each other (like facebook opens messenger).

After a little search i found that i have to know the url scheme of my app, but i don't know how can i declare it. In my urlSchemes are only facebook's schemes.

```
var url  = NSURL(string: "")  
UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!)
```

I found that code and as i understand i have to put in the url my urlScheme.

Any help?

Comment: Can you write a source of plist file?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/mobile/url-schemes

Comment: what part do you want because its too big and it doesn't letting me post it as comment

Comment: @Hodson thnx for your answer will i be able to open another app with this or it's only for safari?

Comment: @mikevorisis You can use it to open your second app from your first app as well as from safari. You may also want to check out the `Deep-linking into an app` tutorial which you can find on the left menu of the tutorial I already linked you to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial on setting up URL Schemes within you app: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/mobile/url-schemes

Incase this tutorial disappears, heres the info:

**Configure our Xcode project**

Go to `Your Target` > Info > URL Types

You need to define your custom URL type. Remember, you want to open the app via `birdland://`, so that will be your URL scheme. We also need to assign an unique identifier to the scheme. Apple recommends that you use reverse DNS notation to ensure that there are no name collisions on the platform, e.g `com.mycompany.ios`.

[image]

That’s it! You’ve configured the app with simple support for the URL scheme `birdland://`. There is, of course, much more that you can do with Custom URL Schemes. To find out more, check out [Apple’s documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html%20).

Now, to check that our registered URL scheme works, we’ll head out to Safari. Press the “Home” button in the Simulator (or press command-shift-H) to reach the Home Screen. Open Safari.

Next, type `birdland://` in the address bar of Safari. Just as you can with http:// URLs, you’re asking Safari to open the “birdland” scheme. Press Go.

Comment: var url  = NSURL(string: "")  
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) == true 
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)

thats the final code after setting up the urlscheme for anyone who want to do this 
you also have to set up the info.plist and put your scheme string under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *openAppURL = @"yourappname://";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:openAppURL]];

//check if app is installed or not
BOOL canOpenURL = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:openAppURL]];
```

Comment: thnx for your answer but this is objective c and it doesn't answer my question.