# How to catch the parameters with branch.io?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I started to use https://branch.io/ in an iOS app.

The problem I am facing now is: how to catch the incoming link with its parameters?

Following the documentation [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/ios/#start-a-branch-session).

I got to this point, having this link:

http://myapp.app.link/A1bcDEFgHi?XP=315.0,419.0

and my code being:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];
    [branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions 
              andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary *params, NSError *error) {
        if (!error && params) {
            NSLog(@"Here is params: %@",params.description); // I need to replace this, with code to get XP!
        }
    }];

    return YES;
}    


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *restorableObjects))restorationHandler
{
    BOOL handledByBranch = [[Branch getInstance] continueUserActivity:userActivity];

    return handledByBranch;
}
```

Here is what I get in the debugging console:

```
2016-06-10 11:59:44.407 TheApp[1786:591391] Here is params: {
    "$identity_id" = 2712491317999770034;
    "$one_time_use" = 0;
    "+click_timestamp" = 1465529273;
    "+clicked_branch_link" = 1;
    "+is_first_session" = 0;
    "+match_guaranteed" = 1;
    XP = "315.0,419.0";
    "~creation_source" = "iOS SDK";
    "~id" = 211224109823923327;
}
```

Now the question is, what is the code to use (inside the app) to get hold of the chunk of data: "315.0,419.0" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alex with Branch here: this is a good question, and one that we should probably make more clear in our docs!

When you generate a link (e.g., http://myapp.app.link/A1bcDEFgHi), you can set whatever data parameters you want and you'll get them back in your `initSessionWithLaunchOptions()` call (as documented [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/ios/#start-a-branch-session)). Your callback data might look something like this:

```
{
    tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2' ],
    channel: 'facebook',
    feature: 'dashboard',
    stage: 'new user',
    data: {
        mydata: 'something',
        foo: 'bar',
    }
}
```

If you append a query to the link URL (e.g., http://myapp.app.link/A1bcDEFgHi?XP=315.0,419.0) we just capture that parameter and pass it through to you:

```
{
    tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2' ],
    channel: 'facebook',
    feature: 'dashboard',
    stage: 'new user',
    data: {
        mydata: 'something',
        foo: 'bar',
        XP: '315.0,419.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, helping me to be on the right track. I now see that the application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler: method is very important in the process. Though I got a big step further ahead, I still have a bit more to go. For that I edited the question, if you have time please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [Best way to parse URL string to get values for keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756683/best-way-to-parse-url-string-to-get-values-for-keys)

There are also third party frameworks you can use to handle this. If you're using Cocoapods, go [here](https://cocoapods.org) and search for "Query".

---

**UPDATE**

I think you need to set up either URL Schemes or Universal Links in your app.

I have answered a previous question about URL Schemes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37541122/1813167) and you can checkout branch.io's documentation on Universal Links [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/overview/)

---

**UPDATE 2**

In your example output you would access `XP` as such `params[@"XP"]` but based on the other answer from [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394680/alex-bauer) you would access it with `params[@"data"][@"XP"]`

Params is just a dictionary so you access it like you would any other dictionary in iOS.

Comment: Yes I have already done that. But how to catch the link from inside the app is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: @Michel - You seem to have got help form Alex. I updated my answer with some information on how you should be able to access your value.

Comment: Rather than params[@"data"][@"XP"] it is [params objectForKey:@"XP"] which works. Anyway that was the idea, thanks. I wish the doc was more explicit sometime :)

Comment: I want to accept the answer. But it's a toughf one. Alex gave me the biggest help, but you hit the last nail :). Alex's answer + your Update 2 = Perfection.