# how to access added parameter in branch deep linking

Tags: android, json, branch.io

This question is not a duplication of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719046/how-to-catch-the-parameters-with-branch-io).I have tried the solution mentioned there but didn't get any luck.

I have added branch.io deep-linking to my app. To test the implementation I have created a link with parameter as described here
  https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#test-deep-link

everything worked fine, but the problem is I can not access the added data from the json object as the json doesn't contain the key I added earlier. I was supposed to get a response like this:

```
    {
  "identity_id": "427469360685348303",
  "link": "https://example.app.link?%24identity_id=427469360685348303",
  "session_id": "429691081177874743",
  "data": {
    "$canonical_identifier": "item/1503684554354.28",
    "$desktop_url": "http://example.com/home",
    "$exp_date": 0,
    "$identity_id": "427469360685348303",
    "$og_description": "My Content Description",
    "$og_image_url": "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/",
    "$og_title": "46D6D28E-0390-40E4-A856-BD74F34D24C8",
    "$publicly_indexable": 1,
    "+click_timestamp": 1503684563,
    "+clicked_branch_link": true,
    "+is_first_session": false,
    "+match_guaranteed": true,
    "custom": "blue",
    "random": "FE848A5B-78F7-42EC-A253-9F795FE91692",
    "added": "1503684554354.33",
    "~campaign": "new launch",
    "~channel": "facebook",
    "~creation_source": 3,
    "~feature": "sharing",
    "~id": 429691043152332059,
    "~referring_link": "https://example.app.link/X7OsnWv9TF",
    "~stage": "new person",
    "~tags": [
      "one",
      "two"
    ]
  }
}
```

But this the response I got:

```
{"+non_branch_link":"https:\/\/qr6x.test-app.link\/g5ynWCX7PI","+clicked_branch_link":false,"+is_first_session":false}
```

here is my code:

```
 Branch branch = Branch.getInstance(context);

    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {
                // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
                // params will be empty if no data found
                // ... insert custom logic here ...


                try {
                    Log.e("myapp","no error");
                    Log.e("myapp", referringParams.toString());

                    String pictureID = referringParams.optString("asdasdasdasd", "");
                    if (pictureID.equals("")) {
                        Log.e("myapp","no ID");
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.e("myapp","ID "+pictureID);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(" " + e.toString());
                }




            } else {
                Log.i("MyApp", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, intent.getData(), activity);
```

can anyone give any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch the parameters with branch.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719046/how-to-catch-the-parameters-with-branch-io)

Answer (score 1):

Jackie from Branch here.
The +non_branch_link typically happens whenever there is an error when creating a Branch Deep Link, or whenever the live_key/test_key get mixed up (i.e. clicking a test link with an app that's using your live key, or vice versa).

Can you confirm that you have the correct Branch test key in the AndroidManifest.xml of your staging app? Here's our [documentation](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#configure-app) on Android app config.

If you continue to experience issues, feel free to send over your APK file to integrations@branch.io and I'd be happy to investigate further for you.